# how to place span tag content next to text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a employee creation form. I am using `bootstrap` for responsiveness. The first field is entering id so I have to check availability of id from database. Here is my markup,

```
<div class="form-group control-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2 "><strong>Teacher Id:</strong>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="col-lg-5 controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id"><span class="status" id="status"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group control-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2"><strong>Name:</strong>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="col-lg-5 controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName" id="teacherName" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The content of `<span class="status" id="status"></span>` will come from jquery ajax call like this,

```
<script>
$("#teacherId").change(function (e) { //user types teacherId on inputfiled
    var teacherId = $(this).val(); //get the string typed by user
    $(".status").html("<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/ajaxLoader.gif' > <font color=gray> Checking availability...</font>");
    if (teacherId != '') {
        $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/TeacherIdCheckController', {
            'teacherId': teacherId
        }, function (data) {
            $('.status').html(data);
        });
    } else {
        $('.status').html('');
    }
});
</script>
```

Here the functionality works fine. I have problem with appearance of content of `<span class="status" id="status"></span>`. It appears in next line, but I want it next to textbox of 'teacherId` So that I can have equal space between all textboxes. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Perhaps providing the CSS you are using "may help" to fix what seems to be a display (CSS) issue then.

Comment: sorry I didnt understand wht u said .

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will be much better...

Comment: @TJ guys check my fiddel but its not correct but u ll get idea, http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/p59qg/

Comment: How about just splitting it up in columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always style the element to position it where ever you wish. Check out the following example

HTML:

```
<div>
THE RED DIV
</div>
<span>NEXT TO RED DIV</span>
```

STYLE:

```
div{
height:100px;
width: 300px;
background-color: RED;   
}
span{
float:right;
margin: -103px 0px 0px 306px;
position: absolute;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vc78/) for implementation.

Also check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re2QX/) which might be helpful in your case

If you could provide the exact fiddle of your page we might be able to give the right fix.

Please let me know if this was helpful.